# start or stop a cloudera manager management service using python API

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am trying to use Cloud era manager python API for starting and stopping the cluster.

IS it possible to stop the management roles also using this API?

IF can you let me know the commands or the documentation page?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example on how to stop Management Services using the python CM API

#### # CM API in python

```
from cm_api.api_client import ApiResource
api = ApiResource("cm-host.cloudera.com")
mgmt = api.get_cloudera_manager().get_service()
```

#### # stop the Mamagement Services

```
mgmt.stop()
```

#### # start the Management Services

```
mgmt.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera Manager provides a number of REST APIs, which also include starting/stopping clusters/services. You can find more from the API documents `[your cloudera manager host]:7180/static/apidocs/`

```
/clusters/{clusterName}/commands/start
/clusters/{clusterName}/commands/stop
/clusters/{clusterName}/services/{serviceName}/commands/start
/clusters/{clusterName}/services/{serviceName}/commands/stop
```

Then there are a number of python modules you could use to visit REST APIs, [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) is one I'd like to recommend.